# Stored Procedure for One to Many insertions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

How can I insert data into a table in the below mentioned format using a stored procedure?

**Req:** Each `DeptCode` will have multiple `EmpName` (unique) which is a dynamic value.

For ex, one of the `DeptCode` may have 20 `EmpName` and other may have just 5. I'm looking for doing something like a batch insert.

**dbo.EmpList**

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| Id | DeptCode  |  EmpName   |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 001       | Tony       |
|  2 | 001       | Steve      |
|  3 | 001       | John       |
|  4 | 001       | Adkins     |
|  5 | 002       | Clark      |
|  6 | 002       | Doe        |
|  7 | 002       | Natasha    |
|  8 | 003       | Thanos     |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EmpList
VALUES ('001', 'Tony'), ('001', 'Steve') 
       .... (And so on for additional data rows)
```

If `Id` is your primary key, it will be added for each row for each insert statement made.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the requirement correctly. I've updated the question. I can do a simple insert statement if I know the number of EmpName entities. But it's dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create sp like that. Of course, you also need to add some controls and validations :

```
DROP PROCEDURE P_InsertEmp
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE P_InsertEmp
     @Id        INT /*If it is identity ignore it*/
    ,@DeptCode  VARCHAR(10)=''
    ,@EmpName   VARCHAR(100)=''
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EmpList
    SELECT @Id,@DeptCode,@EmpName
    SELECT 'Employee has been added'
END

GO

EXEC P_InsertEmp
     @Id        ='1'
    ,@DeptCode  ='001'
    ,@EmpName   ='AA'
```